# Find the longest sequence of consecutive increasing numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

For this example say I have a table with two fields, `AREA varchar(30)` and `OrderNumber INT`.

The table has the following data

```
AREA      | OrderNumber
Fontana   |       32
Fontana   |       42
Fontana   |       76
Fontana   |       12
Fontana   |        3
Fontana   |       99
RC        |       32
RC        |        1
RC        |        8
RC        |        9
RC        |        4
```

**I would like to return**

The results I would like to return is for each area the longest length of increasing consecutive values. For `Fontana it is 3 (32, 42, 76)`. `For RC it is 2 (8,9)`

```
AREA    | LongestLength
Fontana |          3
RC      |          2
```

How would I do this on MS Sql 2005?

Comment: Increasing when ordered by what? There is no inherent order of rows in SQL and neither of the two columns you have shown us are suitable candidates.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the eventtime column which is a datetime which would be what we order by. If i ordered by AREA,OrderNumber the output would like that. Then I would want to find the longest block of consecutively increasing OrderNumbers

Comment: @Pat Rick Allen - Please update your post in accordance with your above clarification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is to use a recursive CTE that steps over each row.  If the row meets the criteria (increasing order number for the same area), you increase the chain length by one.  If it doesn't, you start a new chain:

```
; with  numbered as
        (
        select  row_number() over (order by area, eventtime) rn
        ,       *
        from    Table1
        )
,       recurse as
        (
        select  rn
        ,       area
        ,       OrderNumber
        ,       1 as ChainLength
        from    numbered
        where   rn = 1
        union all
        select  cur.rn
        ,       cur.area
        ,       cur.OrderNumber
        ,       case
                when cur.area = prev.area 
                     and cur.OrderNumber > prev.OrderNumber 
                     then prev.ChainLength + 1
                else 1
                end
        from    recurse prev
        join    numbered cur
        on      prev.rn + 1 = cur.rn
        )
select  area
,       max(ChainLength)
from    recurse
group by
        area
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca3f84/1/0)

An alternative way is to use a query to find "breaks", that is, rows that end a sequence of increasing order numbers for the same area.  The number of rows between breaks is the length.

```
; with  numbered as
        (
        select  row_number() over (order by area, eventtime) rn
        ,       *
        from    Table1 t1
        )
        -- Select rows that break an increasing chain
,       breaks as
        (
        select  row_number() over (order by cur.rn) rn2
        ,       cur.rn
        ,       cur.Area
        from    numbered cur
        left join
                numbered prev
        on      cur.rn = prev.rn + 1
        where   cur.OrderNumber <= prev.OrderNumber
                or cur.Area <> prev.Area
                or prev.Area is null
        )
        -- Add a final break after the last row
,       breaks2 as
        (
        select  *
        from    breaks
        union all
        select  count(*) + 1
        ,       max(rn) + 1
        ,       null
        from    breaks
        )
select  series_start.area
,       max(series_end.rn - series_start.rn)
from    breaks2 series_start
join    breaks2 series_end
on      series_end.rn2 = series_start.rn2 + 1
group by
        series_start.area
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48d5e/1/0)

Comment: I am trying to implement the second solution on the real data, but the real data has a lot more rows and then I get an error "maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion." * I was going to try to the first solution but my real data actually has these rows Eventtime,PublisherID,SubID,CampaignID, Userip whre Userip is the order number in the original example. How do I edit the first solution to add more "AREA" fields.

Comment: Add `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the end of the query

Comment: Also, I convert the USERIP to an integer so you don't need to address that part.

Answer (score 1):

You do not explain why RC's longest sequence does not include 1 while Fontana's does include 32. I take it, the 1 is excluded because it is a decrease: it comes after 32. The Fontana's 32, however, is the first ever item in the group, and I've got two ideas how to explain why it is considered an increase. That's either exactly because it's the group's first item or because it is *also* positive (i.e. as if coming after 0 and, therefore, an increase).

For the purpose of this answer, I'm assuming the latter, i.e. a group's first item is an increase if it is positive. The below script implements the following idea:

1. Enumerate the rows in every `AREA` group in the order of the `eventtime` column you nearly forgot to mention.
2. Join the enumerated set to itself to link every row with it's predecessor.
3. Get the sign of the difference between the row and its preceding value (defaulting the latter to 0). At this point the problem turns into a [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) one.
4. Partition every `AREA` group by the signs determined in #3 and enumerate every subgroup's rows.
5. Find the difference between the row numbers from #1 and those found in #4. That would be a criterion to identify individual streaks (together with `AREA`).
6. Finally, group the results by `AREA`, the sign from #3 and the result from #5, count the rows and get the maximum count per `AREA`.

I implemented the above like this:

```
WITH enumerated AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AREA ORDER BY eventtime)
  FROM atable
),
signed AS (
  SELECT
    this.eventtime,
    this.AREA,
    this.row,
    sgn = SIGN(this.OrderNumber - COALESCE(last.OrderNumber, 0))
  FROM      enumerated AS this
  LEFT JOIN enumerated AS last
    ON this.AREA = last.AREA
   AND this.row  = last.row + 1
),
partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    AREA,
    sgn,
    grp = row - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AREA, sgn ORDER BY eventtime)
  FROM signed
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  AREA,
  LongestIncSeq = MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY AREA)
FROM partitioned
WHERE sgn = 1
GROUP BY
  AREA,
  grp
;
```

A SQL Fiddle demo can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6479b).

Answer (score 0):

You can do some math by `ROW_NUMBER()` to figure out where you have consecutive items.

Here's the code sample:

```
;WITH rownums AS
(
    SELECT [area], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [area] ORDER BY [ordernumber]) AS rid1, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [area] ORDER BY [eventtime]) AS rid2
    FROM SomeTable
),
    differences AS 
(
    SELECT [area],
        [calc] = rid1 - rid2
    FROM rownums
),  
    summation AS
(
    SELECT [area], [calc], COUNT(*) AS lengths 
    FROM differences 
    GROUP BY [area], [calc]
)   
SELECT [area], MAX(lengths) AS LongestLength
FROM differences
JOIN summation
    ON differences.[calc] = summation.[calc]
    AND differences.area = calc.area
GROUP BY [area]
```

So if I do one set of row numbers ordered by my ordernumber and another set of row numbers by my event time, the difference between those two numbers will always be the same, so long as their order is the same.

You can then get a count grouped by those differences and then pull the largest count to get what you need.

EDIT: ...
Ignore the first edit, what I get for rushing.